# update-alternatives, is it *generally* usable?

Tags: python3, update-alternatives, pyside

These links:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=update-alternatives
https://askubuntu.com/search?q=update-alternatives
... do not provide any direct insight into whether `update-alternatives` actually can be used for e.g. using a more recent python, or pyside6 as an alternative for pyside2 (focal).

The man page for 20.04 states:

```
Different packages providing the same file need to do so cooperatively.  In  other  

words,
           the  usage  of update-alternatives is mandatory for all involved packages in such case. It
           is  not  possible  to  override  some  file  in  a  package  that  does  not  employ   the
           update-alternatives mechanism.
```

... which makes me wary of using it (for python and pyside6 specifically right now).

**Any insights into actually using it for e.g. pyside6 specifically?**
*Noted after writing the above: no pyside6 available through apt-get.*

Comment: For Python, no, you can't and you shouldn't even try it as it will re-link the system Python to whatever other Python version you choose and as you might know that wont end well AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the general answer to the usability of `update-alternatives` is:
No
The packages has to cooperate regarding it.

w.r.t. Python and PySide6; Found one option each...

`$ python -m pip install pyside6`
... installs nicely on a fully updated 20.04 at least.

The newer python on the other hand...
I haven't tried it out yet (need a full backup first), but then:

The "deadsnakes ppa" seems to be a usable option - see
https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Google it:
https://www.google.se/search?q=ubuntu+deadsnakes+ppa